# How can I configure the express keys for my Intuos drawing tablet?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, wacom

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and my tablet is CTH-680 or Intuos Pen and Touch Medium.

I used xsetwacom to assign key press a, b, c, d to buttons 1 to 4 of "Wacom Intuos PT M Finger pad" but when I assigned the fourth button, xsetwacom showed me

Unsupported offset into 'Wacom Button Actions' property.

When I tried to test the express keys only thebuttons which were assigned to the  buttons to the left of the tablet worked. The buttons at the right were still the same(forward and back).

When I tried the other devices, the buttons that change are the pen's.

I am still new to Linux, so it would be appreciated if the answer would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

After some searching around, I found this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562

It seems that the buttons are like a mouse's. So there are three buttons for left, right, and middle click, and four buttons are for scroll. Buttons 1 and 2 are the buttons on the upper left of my Intuos and the Buttons for the upper right buttons is Button 8 and 9.

You can get a better explanation from the link.

Answer (score 1):

I'll  try to explain it as simply as i can...

First you get the id of the button you want to set:

Top Left: 3
Bottom Left: 1
Top Right: 9
Bottom Right: 8

Next you need to find the keys you want to "press" when you click the express key. They are pretty self explanatory. For example, the key for"z" is literally "z", and the key for "Ctrl" is also literally "Ctrl". If you want to map a keyboard shortcut to a Express key, you can use the plus symbol to join the two or more characters that make up the shortcut to do it. For example the key for "ctrl-z", the undo shortcut is "Ctrl + Z"

Finally, open the terminal and type in the command:
`xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M Finger pad" Button (button id) "key (corresponding key)"`

As an example if I wanted to map the shortcut "Ctrl-Z" to the top left express key, i would use the command `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT M Finger pad" Button 3 "key control + z"`

Hope I Helped!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current form your answer is not as good as it could be. Could you review [How to Write a Good Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659), and [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers). You could for instance clarify how to determine what the button id's are.