# How to map "mouse wheel up / down" to the express buttons of a Wacom graphics tablet with xsetwacom?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, tablet, wacom, graphics-tablet

I use a "Wacom Intuos" graphics tablet with 4 programmable express buttons under Ubuntu 18.04. Said computer has 2 screens.

I like to assign two buttons of the graphics tablet to the actions "mouse wheel up" and "mouse wheel down". My Goal is to enable zooming without a mouse.

I have therefore determined ...

- ... the names of the tablet components.

  ```
  # get a list of the tablet components
  xsetwacom --list devices

  Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad          id: 12   type: PAD
  Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus       id: 13   type: STYLUS
  Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser       id: 14   type: ERASER
  Wacom Intuos BT S Pen cursor       id: 15   type: CURSOR
  ```
- ... the numerical representations of the mouse actions.

  ```
  # Show mouse events
  xev -event button

  # mouse wheel down
  ButtonPress event ... button 4, ...
  ButtonRelease event ... button 4, ...

  # mouse wheel up
  ButtonPress event, ... button 5, ...
  ButtonRelease event, ... button 5, ...
  ```

The following command should in my understanding assign the "mouse wheel down" action to the 3rd button of the graphics tablet. Unfortunetly, that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 3 4

# I also tried:
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 3 "button 4"
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469925/how-can-i-configure-the-express-keys-for-my-intuos-drawing-tablet#answer-490235) states that the numerical values to refere the express buttons are: 1, 3, 8, 9 (from left to right).
This is not the case with my tablet model. `Button 1`, `Button 2` and `Button 3` are mapped to the first, second and third button of the tablet. (At least my testing has shown that.)

This command is part of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#coding:utf8

main_screen="HEAD-0"
bezier_args="0 20 80 100"
positioning_mode="Absolute"

# Maps the graphics tablet to the area of a specified screen (for multiple-screen environments).
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" MapToOutput "$main_screen"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" MapToOutput "$main_screen"

# Changes the pressure sensitivity.
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" PressureCurve "$bezier_args"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" PressureCurve "$bezier_args"

# Specifies the positioning mode ("Absolute" / "Relative")
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen stylus" Mode "$positioning_mode"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pen eraser" Mode "$positioning_mode"

# Assigns actions to the tablet buttons.
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 1 "key +ctrl z -ctrl"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 2 "key +ctrl +shift z -ctrl -shift"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 3 4

exit 0
```

---

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to use `+` and `-` (from the numpad) instead of `mouse wheel up / down`. Those keys are used by many programs for zooming without a mouse.

```
# Numpad '+'
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 3 "key 0xffab"

# Numpad '-'
xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 8 "key 0xffad"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to use exactly the scroll up and down from the mouse ?

Comment: @CésarArquero Unfortunately no. According to the [xsetwacom documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsetwacom) something like `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos BT S Pad pad" Button 8 4` should work, but I think I never managed to get it work.